# Use Azure CLI commands within VM

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-vm

I am writing a program that uploads a file to Azure blob storage, creates a virtual machine, and now I want to download and execute that file within the VM. For that I am trying to execute the command `az storage blob download <parameters>` in the VM, but unfortunately `az` is not recognized. How can I enable that the Azure CLI is (pre)installed on each new VM? Is there such a possibility provided by Azure? Or should I install the Azure CLI with *yum* for each VM within my script? Any information or ideas is highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Azure CLI yourself. See the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli). You can install it following the steps one by one, or put the commands inside a script and execute the script in the VM extension or cloud-init in the creation time.